# Set HTTP Only cookie with an AWS Authorizer (Cognito or Lambda) using API Gateway V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have an existing API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB RESTful API that is working.

I would like to set up a login system to gate access to this API using Cognito + Cognito (or a custom lambda) Authorizer

I set up Cognito and am able to sign up a user (and also hit a callback URL with a returned `code` to swap for an `access_token` and `id_token`).

My UI is a React app and I am not using Amplify.

Every single tutorial out there suggests you set the callback to your UI (SPA) and parse out the token to use in further API calls. This isn't good because your token is exposed.

I would like to instead set this token in an HTTP-only cookie in the backend, and have it validated when the Cognito (or custom) authorizer is hit.

I also want to check if the token is expired (1 hour) and refresh it with a stored `refresh_token`, and set it for the user again in the same HTTP-only cookie.

Does Cognito Authorizer do this automatically? And if not, how can I do this in the authorizer so I can avoid duplicated code in each of my lambdas (since the authorizer only validates and then passes the request to the lambda, I don't think you can set the response headers then).

Is this even possible?

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I ended up using a custom authorizer to handle the check, if it passes, it goes through to the function with the route handler.

In terms of setting the cookie, this is handled on:
1. Login, the lambda function will handle setting an httpOnly cookie
2. App load, I do an access check and refresh the cookie if it's expired

Comment: AWS Labs has a working version of this here: https://github.com/awslabs/cognito-at-edge/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that Cognito does not support this functionality currently.

It sounds to me like the best approach might actually be to write a simple authentication/identity micro-service which can be responsible for the generation and management of tokens, which abstracts away Cognito from your front-end application. This micro-service could also be responsible for refreshing tokens.

Then you can pass these tokens from your authentication/identity micro-service to any API Gateway you have hooked up with a Cognito authoriser.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was worried it might be like this. Feels like I might have to go the custom lambda authorized route because I don't believe you can customize a Cognito outside of some of the configs AWS provides? Haven't looked too deeply but I think if the domain is the same, I can write a single route->lambda that can set the http-only cookie and the app can call that on load